# Free energy calculations for lammps

Tags: molecular-dynamics, reference-request, lammps, software-input-file-request, free-energy

Is there any tutorial or reference available to perform free energy calculations (umbrella sampling; thermodynamic integration; free energy perturbation; wisdom's particle insertion method) etc. with LAMMPS? I want to see an example code from a project that has fully done these calculations.

Thanks.